# magento 2 custom module, list view show blank page

Tags: magento2, frontend

`app/code/Smartshore/Subscription/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Smartshore_Subscription" setup_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

`app/code/Smartshore/Subscription/etc/frontend/routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="smartshore" frontName="smartshore">
            <module name="Smartshore_Subscription" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

`app/code/Smartshore/Subscription/Controller/Subscription/Index.php`

```
<?php

namespace Smartshore\Subscription\Controller\Subscription;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

Class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {

        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();

    }

}
```

`app/code/Smartshore/Subscription/Block/PostList.php`

```
<?php

namespace Smartshore\Subscription\Block;11

use Smartshore\Subscription\Api\Data\PostInterface;
use Smartshore\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Collection as PostCollection;

class PostList extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements
    \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    protected $_postCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Ashsmith\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Post\CollectionFactory $postCollectionFactory,
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Smartshore\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Post\CollectionFactory $postCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_postCollectionFactory = $postCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Smartshore\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Collection
     */
    public function getPosts()
    {
        // Check if posts has already been defined
        // makes our block nice and re-usable! We could
        // pass the 'posts' data to this block, with a collection
        // that has been filtered differently!
        if (!$this->hasData('posts')) {
            $posts = $this->_postCollectionFactory
                ->create()
                ->addFilter('status', 1)
                ->addOrder(
                    PostInterface::CREATION_TIME,
                    PostCollection::SORT_ORDER_DESC
                );
            $this->setData('posts', $posts);
        }
        return $this->getData('posts');
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [\Smartshore\Subscription\Model\Post::CACHE_TAG . '_' . 'list'];
    }
}
```

`app/code/Smartshore/Subscription/view/frontend/layout/subscription_subscription_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Smartshore\Subscription\Block\PostList" name="post.list" template="Smartshore_Subscription::list.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

`app/code/Smartshore/Subscription/view/frontend/templates/list.phtml`

```
<?php /** @var $block \Ashsmith\Blog\Block\PostList */ ?>
<h1><?php echo __('Latest Posts') ?></h1>
<ul class="blog-post-list">
<?php /** @var $post \Ashsmith\Blog\Model\Post */ ?>
<?php foreach ($block->getPosts() as $post): ?>
    <li class="blog-post-list-item">
        <h3 class="blog-post-item-title">
            <a href="<?php echo $post->getContent() ?>"><?php echo $post->getTitle() ?></a>
        </h3>

        <div class="blog-post-item-content">
            <?php echo $post->getContent(); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="blog-post-item-meta">
            <strong><?php echo __('Created at:') ?></strong> <?php echo $post->getCreationTime() ?>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Route is  >> http://local.magento2.com/smartshore/subscription/index

Answer (score 2):

you have this line `namespace Smartshore\Subscription\Block;11` in `app/code/Smartshore/Subscription/Block/PostList.php`, remove the `11` at the end of the line.